# Unity 2D - scale sprite according to screen width

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites

So I have a square sprite (width == height) and I want to scale it so that both width and height are exactly one fifth of the width screen. To find the desired pixel width I do:
`float desiredWidthPixels = Screen.width * 0.2f;
float desiredHeightPixels = Screen.width * 0.2f;`

How do I apply these values to the sprite?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to actually resize the sprite. What you want to do is resize the *texture* this sprite is being rendered on.

Once you get the texture you can call `Texture2D.Resize(Screen.width * 0.2f, Screen.width * 0.2f)`

If you're not sure which texture you are using, you can call `Sprite.texture` to get the texture used. If you wanted to, you could even do `Sprite.texture.Resize(width, height)`.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite-texture.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Resize.html